# Magento CMS Page showing odd site link on google search result

Tags: magento2, google

When you search for our domain name on Google you will see site links under the description. Usually the site links would be named after the page however now one of them is saying "Viagra Online Echeck". None of the site content has changed. Literally nothing was touched.

Does anyone know how you can change this? I heard there is a way to add meta tags to the CMS pages but I cannot find how to do this.

Comment: Sounds like you've been hacked

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CMS >> Page >> Add/ edit you find the META tab in that you can add Keywords and Description. and title will come form Page Information >> Page Title.